# Project Euler #10, My (wrong) solution is 100x slower than preferred

Tags: python, performance

The preferred solution finishes in around 0.363s

```
sieve = [True] * 2000000

def mark(sieve, x):
    for i in range(x+x, len(sieve), x):
        sieve[i] = False

for x in range(2, int(len(sieve) ** 0.5) +1):
    if sieve[x]: mark(sieve, x)

print (sum(i for i in range(2, len(sieve)) if sieve[i]))
```

however my solution (which is also wrong), for some reason, takes about 13-14 seconds to execute. I'm curious what is slowing mine down so much.

```
val = 2000000
stop = int(floor(sqrt(val)))
print("stop: " + str(stop))
sieve = [x for x in range(2,val)]

def remove_nonprimes(sieve, p):
    markset = set(sieve[p-2::p][1::])
    sieve = list(filter(lambda x: x not in markset, sieve))
    return sieve

for p in range(2, stop):
    if(p in sieve):
        sieve=remove_nonprimes(sieve, p)

print(str(sum(sieve)))
```

Comment: Think about it, for every iteration where a value is in the sieve, you're creating a _new_ sieve every time. With sqrt(2000000) values to go through and 2000000 item sieve, that's going to be _a lot_ of iterations.

Comment: thanks! also just realised my solution is wrong somehow, that's odd, don't understand why.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein: Thanks for the link--it contains much I did not know. Note that I did not downvote this question or vote to close it, since I was not sure.